# Is there a way to graph an accumulation of simultaneous tasks happening at the same time in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a list of tasks that each have a start and end time. Is there a way to visually see an accumulation of tasks that are happening at any given time?

Basically, I'm looking for a graph, or even a function, that would show me the sum of tasks given a certain time.

My data is formatted like so:

```
Name    Task Start  Task End
Task 1  5:29    6:19
Task 2  6:01    6:51
Task 3  6:13    7:03
Task 4  6:17    7:07
Task 5  6:17    7:07
Task 6  6:17    7:07
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use COUNTIFS() for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out one possible solution. I decided to use VBA to just iterate through predetermined times (i.e. 00:00, 00:15, ...), and for each one, count how many tasks it fell within.

Here is some simplified code of what I did:

```
Private Sub Calculate_Demand()

Dim demandCount As Integer

For i = 2 To 97
    demandCount = 0
    For j = 2 To 564 
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tasks").Cells(j, 2) <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Time").Cells(i, 1) And ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tasks").Cells(j, 3) >= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Time").Cells(i, 1) Then demandCount = demandCount + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Time").Cells(i, 2).Value = demandCount
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Where "Tasks" was formatted as:

```
Name    Task Start  Task End
Task 1  5:29    6:19
Task 2  6:01    6:51
Task 3  6:13    7:03
Task 4  6:17    7:07
Task 5  6:17    7:07
Task 6  6:17    7:07
```

and "Time" was formatted as:

```
Time    Tasks
5:30    1
5:45    1
6:00    1
6:15    3
6:30    10
```

I then just graphed the results, and called it good!